# Cannot open parquet file giving path of directory

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

This might be  a stupid question but imma try anyway. I am trying to do a simple exercise with spark. I read that if i have frammented parquet to open i can just use the path of the folder and it's supposed to open them all. I don't understand why I have errors tho. I used absolute path, relative path (copied using VSC), i tried using import os the get the exact one but still no luck. I keep getting an error in the spark.read.parquet.
I think it's the path at this point, but if i simply add to the path the name of a single parquet in that folder, it works. It gets opened. What am I doing wrong?

The errors:
An error occurred while calling o30.parquet.

Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicabl

org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

#   Initialize the Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local") \
    .config("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1) \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "500mb") \
    .appName("Exercise1") \
    .getOrCreate()
    
#   Read the source tables in Parquet format
products_table = spark.read.parquet("data/products_parquet")
sales_table = spark.read.parquet("data/sales_parquet")
sellers_table = spark.read.parquet("data/sellers_parquet")
```

I am also giving an image of the folders structure

[image]

Comment: Can you show more of the error? And the contents of the folder? It looks like you're trying to read a folder, instead of a parquet file (ending with .parquet in the path)

Comment: Inside a folder there are several .parquet partitioned files and some .crc files. The path is indeed that of the folder, because i read that adding the path of the folder meant opening all the files in it. In the solution of the exercise, it's done in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this issue is specifically related to hadoop binaries not found on your windows system. This is the known problem on Windows, basically hadoop requires native libraries on windows in order to access the filesystem essentially this is required to implement posix like file permissions.

##### How to resolve this issue?

- Clone/download the  [this repo](https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils/tree/master/).
- Copy the hadoop folder corresponding to your spark version in the local dir. For example if your spark version is `3.0.0` then copy `hadoop-3.0.0` and place this on some path lets say `C:\spark\hadoop-3.0.0`
- Create a new environment variable in your system called `HADOOP_HOME` and set the value of this variable to `C:\spark\hadoop-3.0.0\bin`
- Restart VS code (if restarting vs code dosnt work..simply restart the system)
- That's it.

FYI. here is the link to spark docs corresponding to [this issue](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/WindowsProblems)